# how to install yoono-desktop-1.8.43.tar.bz2 in linux

Tags: software-installation, tar, application

I recently yoono-desktop from http://www.yoono.com/desktop_features.html .How to install this file.

Comment: Which distribution are you using?

Comment: distribution means..?

Comment: Like Debian, Ubuntu, Fedora, Linux Mint and similar.

Comment: linux (centos 6.4)

Comment: are u there...??

Comment: Seems like you don't have to install it, just extract it like this: `tar xvjf yoono-desktop-1.8.43.tar.bz2` and then go to the directory. There (or maybe in some dir inside it) will be file called yoono-desktop. Do this: `chmod u+x yoono-desktop` and then this: `./yoono-desktop` It should open now.

Comment: @RistoSalminen Please post this as an answer.

Comment: @JosephR. I will.

Comment: [root@localhost mpatil]# tar xvjf yoono-desktop-1.8.43.tar.bz2
tar (child): yoono-desktop-1.8.43.tar.bz2: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Comment: @ram you should first go to the directory: `cd ~/Desktop/Ram/Downloads/`

Comment: NOTE: Direct download link to the Linux version of s/w is here: http://cdn.yoono.com/desktop/yoono-desktop-1.8.43.tar.bz2

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you don't have to install it, just do run these commands:

- First, download `yoono-desktop`:

  ```
  wget http://cdn.yoono.com/desktop/yoono-desktop-1.8.43.tar.bz2
  ```
- Extract the file

  ```
  tar xvjf yoono-desktop-1.8.43.tar.bz2
  ```
- Go to the directory

  ```
  cd yoono-desktop
  ```
- Then run yoono

  ```
  ./yoono-desktop
  ```

Comment: @ram Why are you doing this as root? Try running it as your regular user.

Comment: @ram you have to extract it as regular user, then you can do all the operations as regular user